# How do I pass values from an input tag into a page item variable

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to get user input from a PL/SQL Dynamic Content table defined using html.

```
declare
var_input number;
var_input_1 number;
begin
    sys.htp.p(' <TR style="height:20px;"><TH> 16 Weeks <td><input type="text" id="ID1" 
       style="width:50px;" value="">sys.htp.p(' <TR style="height:20px;"><TH> 16 Weeks <td> 
       <input type="text" id="ID2" style="width:50px;" value=" ">');
end;
```

How do I pass the values associated with ID1 and ID2 into var_input and var_input_1 respectively?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is Oracle APEX, as this tag is missing yet.
In APEX, you can use the apex_application package and its global variables to access custom form items.
For your example, use the name attribute to let APEX know which variables to use.

```
<input type="text" id="ID1" name="F01" />
<input type="text" id="ID2" name="F02" />
```

After submitting, you can access the entered data using `apex_application.g_f01` and `apex_application.g_f02`. There are variables up to `g_f50`. See the following page for more details:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/AEAPI/Referencing-Arrays.htm#AEAPI215

Note that all you do can be done without using sys.htp or apex_application using the built in page items of APEX.